# Compare encrypted strings with strcmp

Tags: c, c-strings, cs50

I am trying to fill the gaps in my self-education in computer science and taking the CS50 course on Edx. I am completely new to C. In one of the problems sets, I have to compare strings encrypted with crypt function.

In the following example, I cannot understand why `strcmp` returns 0 (i.e. 'claims' that the strings are equal:

```
#include <crypt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define _XOPEN_SOURCE

int main(void)
{
    char string1[4] = "foo\0";
    char string2[4] = "bar\0";

    printf("crypt1: %s\n",crypt(string1, "50\0"));
    printf("crypt2: %s\n",crypt(string2, "50\0"));

    if (strcmp(crypt(string1, "50\0"),crypt(string2, "50\0")) == 0)
    {
        printf("crypt1: %s\n",crypt(string1, "50\0"));
        printf("crypt2: %s\n",crypt(string2, "50\0"));
        return 0;
    }
}
```

When I run the program, the output value is:

```
crypt1: 50GbL/FUeE/J6
crypt2: 50hmnpE.bRNiU
crypt1: 50GbL/FUeE/J6
crypt2: 50hmnpE.bRNiU
```

How is it possible, that the code inside `if` condition is even executed?

Comment: Apparently, `crypt()` uses the *same buffer* for the encrypted string on each call.

Comment: Btw, a string literal `"foo"` already ends with `\0`.

Comment: Consider switching to use `crypt_r()`, if available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, `crypt()` uses the same buffer for the encrypted string on each call:

```
char string1[] = "foo";
char string2[] = "bar";

char *crypt1 = crypt(string1, "50");
printf("crypt1: %s\n", crypt1); // crypt1: 50GbL/FUeE/J6

char *crypt2 = crypt(string2, "50");
printf("crypt1: %s\n", crypt1); // crypt1: 50hmnpE.bRNiU
printf("crypt2: %s\n", crypt2); // crypt2: 50hmnpE.bRNiU
```

In order to keep (and compare) both results, you have to `strdup()`
them or copy them to a separate array.

Comment: @Doug: Thanks for the edit suggestion. However, I think that adding that information to *your* answer is sufficient.

Comment: yes - I accidentally added it to yours first.  Sadly, stack overflow doesn't support deleting edits :-/

Comment: Just to point out that although `strdup()` is a common extension, it is not standard C.  But it's not hard to write one if it's not provided.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in Martin's comment, crypt returns a pointer to a static buffer that is overwritten on each call.  So strcmp is actually being passed the same buffer - the first value of crypt already having been overwritten by the second - once the two arguments have been evaluated.

Related to the following: [C crypt function, malloc and valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764339/c-crypt-function-malloc-and-valgrind)

[And, for what its worth, in C, any function that returns a string (char *) has to get the memory for that string from somewhere.  You either need to pass the buffer in as an argument, or it needs to find it itself.  And because C doesn't do garbage collection and requires manual memory management (e.g. malloc/free), a function that does not take a result buffer as an argument should throw up a red flag - is the result a static buffer (that gets overwritten like this)? does it need to be free'd when I'm done with it?  Otherwise, you risk memory leaks or bugs like the one you're experiencing.)

Comment: Yes, see `man 3 crypt` for details on hash size for proper sizing of storage for the return.

Comment: Your final paragraph is the real insight here.